# MySQL query to group messages into a conversation and show the first in the inbox

Tags: mysql, database

Say for example two users talk via direct message, you will have a conversation of messages .. I want to just select the latest message from that conversation and then show it as the conversation link in their message inbox ... just how Facebook and Twitter messages work. They can then click that last sent message to view the whole conversation.

My messages table that contains all messages sent between users is in the following format:

sourceUserId is the id of the user who sent the message, targetUserId is the id of the user who received the message, body is the message, time is a timestamp of when the message was sent. I have kept body as abc... and time 1234 to keep this example simple, they are all different values.

```
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | sourceUserId | targetUserId |  body  | time |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 2  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 3  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 4  |       1      |       3      | abc... | 1234 |
| 5  |       2      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 6  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 7  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 8  |       4      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 9  |       5      |       4      | abc... | 1234 |
| 10 |       3      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

To get all the messages (sent and received) for one user, I use this query:

```
SELECT sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE targetUserId = 1
OR sourceUserId = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10

+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | sourceUserId | targetUserId |  body  | time |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 2  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 3  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 4  |       1      |       3      | abc... | 1234 |
| 5  |       2      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 6  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 7  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 8  |       4      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

**but** it returns multiple instances of the same message conversation and not just the latest message from a conversation between two users. Take for example rows 2,3 and 4 would all show exactly the same conversation.

I can get the query to work for just targetUserId (messages the user has received) with the following query:

```
SELECT sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE targetUserId = 1
GROUP BY sourceUserId
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10

+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | sourceUserId | targetUserId |  body  | time |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 2  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 5  |       2      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 8  |       4      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

and the opposite (messages sent by the user) with this, note that WHERE and GROUP BY have just been swapped:

```
SELECT sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE sourceUserId = 1
GROUP BY targetUserId
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10

+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | sourceUserId | targetUserId |  body  | time |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 4  |       1      |       3      | abc... | 1234 |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

but if I combine the two results and `group by targetUserId, sourceUserId` then it does not give the correct result because all outgoing messages from 1 to (2,3,4) are grouped.

**What I would like to return**

I think the Pseudo Code for such a query would be:

```
SELECT sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE sourceUserId = 1
OR targetUserId = 1
GROUP BY (If targetUserId != 1), (If sourceUserId != 1)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10

+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| id | sourceUserId | targetUserId |  body  | time |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1  |       1      |       2      | abc... | 1234 |
| 2  |       3      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
| 8  |       4      |       1      | abc... | 1234 |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: If you `GROUP BY targetUserId`, you will only get one message per 'target user', which is nothing like the output you show.  You say your first query returns "multiple instances of the same conversation" - how does one identify to which "conversation" a message belongs?  I can't see how your desired output relates to your example table.

Comment: @eggyal I know, I haven't shown an output? The output is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Is not the table beneath "*ideally it would return the below if the :userId was 1*" your desired output?  What is that?

Comment: @eggyal I have updated the question, does it make sense now? I just want to get all results `where sourceUserId=1 or targetUserId=1` and remove opposite duplicates.

Comment: What's not clear to me is what you mean by "opposite duplicates".  I can't see how your "What I would like to return" table relates to the messages table shown at the top of your question... why aren't the records with `id IN (3,4,5,6,7)` included - they all have either source or target user id 1?  As asked in my first comment: "*how does one identify to which "conversation" a message belongs?*"

Comment: Simpler explanation: If the targetUserId or sourceUserId = 1 then it should group by which ever is not 1.

Comment: I suspect this task would be considerably easier if you added a `conversation_id` column to the table, then one would merely need to `GROUP BY` that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VERSION 2 
This is untested; it is closer but still not right... out of time though on working on this...

```
SELECT Um1.sourceUserId, Um1.targetUserId, um1.body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(um1.time)  
FROM usermessages um1
WHERE um1.time = 
   (Select max(um1.time) 
    FROM usermessages um2 
    where um1.sourceUserID = um2.sourceUserID 
      and Um1.targetUserID = Um2.targetUserID, 
      and UM1.Body = UM2.body 
      and (targetuserID = 1 or sourceuserID = 1))
Group by Um1.sourceUserId, Um1.targetUserId, um1.body
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

VERSION 1 (Miss)
IMO you need to group by body as well.

```
SELECT sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE targetUserId = 1
OR sourceUserId = 1
GROUP BY sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Or use distinct

```
SELECT distinct sourceUserId, targetUserId, body,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)  
FROM `usermessages`
WHERE targetUserId = 1
OR sourceUserId = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I think the problem is really in that body is different or timestamp is different for those records; if not, then why are they duplicated in the table?    Specifically in your output why are records 1 & 6 there... are you missing a unique index/pk which would prevent duplicates?

Comment: Each entry in this table is a message from one user to another, the body is the message content and the time is the timestamp of when the message was sent. Users can send multiple messages to one another so there is always duplicates in this instant. My aim is to get just the last message between two users to display as the most recent unread message in the inbox, when this is clicked I can then display the whole conversation history.

Comment: If you AIM is to get the last message between two users  then you want a max on timestamp that is unique between two users  If I sent it you would show me the message i sent, whereas you would see the message you received... is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly, but only ever show one conversation between two users in the message inbox.